# What is the significance of Shikha?

Tags: rituals, brahmins, samskara

Brahmins and temple priests have/kept **Shikha (शिखा)**/choti (tuft of hair) at the back of head head. So,

- What is the significance of Shikha?
- In other word : What is the purpose/importance? What Shikha indicates/stands for?
- Who must have Shika?

Comment: You may visit http://www.indiadivine.org/why-do-hindus-wear-the-tuft-of-hair-called-shikha

Answer (score 1):

> 12. Choti on the Male Head
>
> Sushrut rishi, the foremost surgeon of Ayurveda, describes the master
>   sensitive spot on the head as Adhipati Marma, where there is a nexus
>   of all nerves. The shikha protects this spot. Below, in the brain,
>   occurs the Brahmarandhra, where the sushumnã (nerve) arrives from the
>   lower part of the body. In Yog, Brahmarandhra is the highest, seventh
>   chakra, with the thousand-petalled lotus. It is the centre of wisdom.
>   The knotted shikhã helps boost this centre and conserve its subtle
>   energy known as ojas.

[hindu-traditions-scientific-reasons](http://desinema.com/hindu-traditions-scientific-reasons/)

Comment: You should cite some sources for Brahmarandhra and Ayurveda