# Significance of five shikhas (tuft) during upanayanam

Tags: rituals, shikha, upanayanam

Most of traditional brahmins have a [Shikha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikha) (long tuft in english) at back of their head.  Shikha is believed to posses great power and so it is touched to establish a power source inside it during [nyasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyasa_%28ritual%29) process. But a child is initiated into the stage of Brahmachari, a ceremony called Upanayanam(sacred thread ceremony) is held. During this ceremony, the child is left with five shikhas in five directions.

What is the significance of these five shikhas. Is this tradition limited to some states and some sects of brahmins or is it same for every sect?

Comment: [Not Duplicate but Related] [What is the significance of Shikha?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8521/3500) and [Why is Shikha Bandhan needed at the time of pooja?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8499/3500)